# Positioning pop up windows on screen: how to make them not overlay?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, dom-events

I use such script to open pop-ups :

```
<script>
var wins = [];
openWin = function(name, width, height, left, top){
    left=left+1;
    top=top+1;
    var file='./'+name+'.flv?action=read';
    var settings='width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top+'';
     wins.push(window.open(file, name, settings));
         
           for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; ++i)
            wins[i].focus();

}
</script>
```

This is only function I use to open pop-ups, but I'd love to get rid of `left, top` params to make them more automated... for them to calculate themselves based on number of previously opened windows and `screen.width` and `screen.height`. So generally I want to achieve some kind of grid of pop-ups.

My main problem - I do not see how to change horizontal rows with JS knowing that height and width may vary.

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the screen height, determine where you want to place your first window and store them as variables. Every time you open a new window increment the variables that stored the x and y of the first window by a constant and they will open in a cascading fashion. There are many ways to do this depending on how you want it to work.

Comment: I wanted a grid, not cascade=) It seems grid is bit more complex because I do not see how to find a point of getting to a new row using JS...